# Combine Cell Text Details

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to combine these three lines to be shorter? I use these lines multiple times for different column indexes, so it is a lot of repeating. I am wondering if there is a better way to approach this method. For `sysnum` it is defined in code that I did not include because it did not seem relevant, but it is a text string of numbers.

Here is my code:

```
Dim lastrow As Long, sysnum as String 
lastrow = wb.Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row 

wb.Worksheets(sysnum).Rows(lastrow + 1).Insert
wb.Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = sysnum
wb.Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Font.Bold = True

wb.Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = "Passed"
wb.Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
wb.Worksheets(sysnum).Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen

End If
```

Comment: Use a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a little better if you do this:

```
  Dim lastrow As Long, sysnum As String
  

  With wb.Worksheets(sysnum)
      lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      .Rows(lastrow + 1).Insert
      .Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = sysnum
      .Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Font.Bold = True
      
      .Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = "Passed"
      .Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
      .Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
  End With
```

but any time you find yourself copy/pasting the same code everywhere - you should try to abstract that code into a sub-routine.  Perhaps:

```
Sub ResetColors(ByVal sheetToChange as Worksheet)
    With sheetToChange 
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Rows(lastrow + 1).Insert
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Value = sysnum
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 2).Font.Bold = True
        
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Value = "Passed"
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, 3).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End With
End Sub
```

Then you call that subroutine by calling "ResetColors Sheet1" ... or "ResetColors ActiveSheet"

EDIT:

1. as BigBen suggested - changed the sub to accept a Sheet object instead of the index.  I can't say why - but that does seem "better"
2. If you wanted to call that subroutine for every sheet you would do:

```
dim sht as worksheet
For Each sht in thisworkbook.sheets
   ResetColors sht
Next
```

Comment: For your `Sub ResetColors` function, I plan on using it within a for each loop, so to call it would I just say `ResetColors ActiveSheet.Index` like you suggested and that will loop through all the worksheets?

Comment: A suggestion: it'd be better for `ResetColors` to accept a `Worksheet` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

### Create a Method For Repeating Code

**Usage**

```vb
Sub CallSysNumInsert()

    ' These two are already declared somewhere in your code!
    ' They are here only for the code to be able to compile.
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sysnum As String

    ' Call the method.    
    SysNumInsert wb, sysnum

End Sub
```

**The Method**

- Rename the method appropriately.

```vb
Sub SysNumInsert(ByVal wb As Workbook, ByVal WorksheetName As String)
    With wb.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
        Dim dRow As Long: dRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Rows(dRow).Insert
        With .Cells(dRow, "B")
            .Value = WorksheetName
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With
        With .Cells(dRow, "C")
            .Value = "Passed"
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```